# discord.js pushing roles into a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i made this mute command that should save roles into a const:

```
// Variable for saving roles
        const savedRoles = []
// Mute   
muteUser.roles.set([muteRole]).catch(console.error);
muteUser.roles.cache.array()
savedRoles.push(muteUser.roles.cache.array())
```

i also made this unmute command:

```
 // Unmute
        muteUser.roles.remove(muteRole)
        muteUser.roles.add(savedRoles)
```

the mute works but when i try to unmute and give back the saved roles (that i don't think were even saved so maybe that's the problem but i'm not sure) the bot crashes saying: "savedRoles is not defined"

if you're wondering what muteUser and muteRole are they're some const i made:

```
const muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");
const muteUser = message.mentions.members.first();
```

anyway mute and unmute are in the same file. I hope you can help

Comment: `savedRoles` is only saved in the instance of `mute`, once the instance ends the array and emptied. Either you need to declare the variable in a global scope or better yet use a database. Even if `savedRoles` was filled, it would not exist in `unmute`

Answer (score 0):

what do you use as database, if you use mongodb you need to define your database somehow and go into the schema and save it there like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const guildSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  guildID: String,
  guildName: String,
  savedRoles: {
    "type": Array,
    "default":[]
  }
```

you can then save it in the file by doing like this

```
const settings = await client.getGuild(message.guild);

const role = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[1]);
    if(!role) return message.channel.sendErrorMessage('Role is not valid!');
    if(settings) {
        if(settings.savedRoles.includes(role.id)) return message.channel.sendErrorMessage('This role is already a savedrole');
  
    await settings.savedRoles.push(role.id);
 } else {
    settings = message.guild, 
    { savedRoles: role.id }
}
    await settings.save();
    message.channel.sendSuccessMessage(`\`${role.name}\` is now saved`)
```

Comment: The thing is, i don't use any database, and tbh i would prefer to not use them

Comment: if you don't use a database then its not possbile for multi guild functionallity but if you want to have it for a personal server that is more easier